# Вопросы/ответы с нелегальным содержимым

Tags: обсуждение, правки, авторские-права

Есть ли общая позиция по этому вопросу? Просто некоторое недоумение вызвали правки [вот этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/39195/179921). Т.е. с одной стороны "зашифровали", но при должном любопытстве оригинал можно увидеть. Кроме того это входит в противоречие с конецепцией правки, когда не допускается искажение смысла. Т.к. некие абстрактные "C++ Builder Видео уроки" это не что-то конкретное что имел в виду автор ответа. На мой взгляд ответ просто должен быть удалён, а ссылки на нелигитимный контент запрещены.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы имели в виду нелегальный? ([Легитимность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)).

Comment: Да, конечно, что-то я перемудрил :)

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

- Все ссылки на нелегальный контент — вычищать.
- Если можно идентифицировать объект по  метаинформации — заменить ей ссылку. Напишите, как называется книга или видео, кто автор, два слова описания.
- Если название абстрактное («Видеоуроки по программированию») — выбросить, не жалея.
- Если ответ состоит только из ссылок — ничего нового, мы его удаляем.

#### Подробно

Это была попытка немного улучшить плохой ответ на плохой вопрос.

**Ссылки на видео**

- Единственный случай, когда ссылку можно заменить на голый текст — когда это авторские уроки, т.е. можно сказать «Уроки по Borland C++ Builder от Дмитрия Иванова, поищите в сети».
- Ссылку можно оставить, если это легальный контент, например лекции Технопарка Mail.ru или Youtube.
- Но в целом нет смысла давать такие ссылки. Думаю, что поисковики индексируют торрент-трекеры и видеохостинги не хуже, чем StackOverflow, так что по запросу «Самоучитель Borland C++» раньше будет ссылка на само видео, чем на SO.

**Ссылки на книги**

- Если бы была ссылка на книгу, можно было бы на название и автора самой книги. Читатель поймет, что рекомендовано, а получить книгу может удобным ему способом: в книжном, в интернет-магазине, в библиотеке.

**Ссылки на нелегальный контент:**

Считаю, что их нужно запрещать. При том, что обстановка с авторскими правами постоянно ужесточается, такие ссылки могут создавать опасность для StackOverflow. Возможно, когда-нибудь станет незаконно размещать даже ссылки на пиратский контент, и тогда нам придется оперативно их искать и вычищать.

Comment: Кроме того, ссылки (особенно «подпольные») подвержены общей проблеме: они устаревают. Особенно ссылки на торренты — трекер вполне может поменять имя и домен, или быть доступен только с зеркала. Так что согласен, вместо прямой ссылки должна быть метаинформация: как называется книга, кто автор, два слова описания. А уж где и как искать книгу, каждый пусть решает себе сам.

Comment: @VladD: да-да, там из трех ссылок две уже невалидны. Спасибо за уточнение про метаинформацию, включу в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Мы поддерживаем интеллектуальную собственность и права на интеллектуальную собственность. Все вопросы

- про взломанное ПО;
- то как взломать ПО;
- содержащие ссылки на сервера с нелегальным содержимым;
- и т. д.

Следует удалять.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую следует указывать причину для удаления?